# Using two related xml elemnts for xsl:key

Tags: xslt, xpath

Using XSLT 1.0, is it possible to create a xsl:key based off of two "related" xml elements?

For example, I'd like to create a key which concatenates the values of:

1. `/component/section/text/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/text()`
2. `/component/section/entry/act/effectiveTime/low/@value`

Ideally, the key would looks somethings like:

1. `test description|20161229000000`
2. `test description2|20161230000000`

These elements are related in the sense that they share a sibling element with same reference id (`ref_b71a6ee05ef245f1a0c3f302ca769077_pastIllness_name_*`) as an attribute.

When defining a key, it is required to specify a "match" xpath pattern, and a "use" xpath pattern. But it seems difficult to create a pattern that could account for a related attribute with a certain value, especially when the elements have different parent elements and the related attribute value differs for each pair of related elements.

Sample xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
  <component>
    <section classCode="DOCSECT" moodCode="EVN">
        <text mediaType="text/x-hl7-text+xml">
            <table border="1">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td ID="ref_b71a6ee05ef245f1a0c3f302ca769077_pastIllness_name_1">test description</td>
                        <td ID="ref_b71a6ee05ef245f1a0c3f302ca769077_pastIllness_dateOfOnset_1">12/29/2016</td>
                        <td ID="ref_b71a6ee05ef245f1a0c3f302ca769077_pastIllness_comments_1"/>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td ID="ref_b71a6ee05ef245f1a0c3f302ca769077_pastIllness_name_2">test description2</td>
                        <td ID="ref_b71a6ee05ef245f1a0c3f302ca769077_pastIllness_dateOfOnset_2">12/30/2016</td>
                        <td ID="ref_b71a6ee05ef245f1a0c3f302ca769077_pastIllness_comments_2"/>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </text>
        <entry>
            <act classCode="ACT" moodCode="EVN">
                <id extension="1206ca2c614d4d07990b0162ee99aaf1" root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.441"/>
                <code nullFlavor="NA"/>
                <statusCode code="completed"/>
                <effectiveTime>
                    <low value="20161229000000"/>
                    <high nullFlavor="UNK"/>
                </effectiveTime>
                <entryRelationship inversionInd="false" typeCode="SUBJ">
                    <observation classCode="OBS" moodCode="EVN" negationInd="false">
                        <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.28"/>
                        <id extension="99999999" root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.441.1.50.869.51.1349970.61"/>
                        <code code="55607006"
                            codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.96"
                            codeSystemName="SNOMED CT" displayName="undescriptive display name"/>
                        <text>
                            <reference value="#ref_b71a6ee05ef245f1a0c3f302ca769077_pastIllness_name_1"/>
                        </text>
                        <statusCode code="completed"/>
                        <effectiveTime>
                            <low value="20161229000000"/>
                        </effectiveTime>
                        <value code="783.3" codeSystemName="ICD9" displayName="undescriptive display name">
                            <originalText>ref_b71a6ee05ef245f1a0c3f302ca769077_pastIllness_name_1</originalText>
                        </value>
                        <entryRelationship inversionInd="false" typeCode="REFR">
                            <observation classCode="OBS" moodCode="EVN">
                                <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.50"/>
                                <code code="33999-4"
                                    codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1"
                                    codeSystemName="LOINC" displayName="Status"/>
                                <statusCode code="Completed"/>
                                <value code="73425007"
                                    codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.96"
                                    codeSystemName="SNOMED CT" displayName="InActive"/>
                            </observation>
                        </entryRelationship>
                    </observation>
                </entryRelationship>
            </act>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <act classCode="ACT" moodCode="EVN">
                <id extension="1206ca2c614d4d07990b0162ee99aaf1" root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.441"/>
                <code nullFlavor="NA"/>
                <statusCode code="completed"/>
                <effectiveTime>
                    <low value="20161230000000"/>
                    <high nullFlavor="UNK"/>
                </effectiveTime>
                <entryRelationship inversionInd="false" typeCode="SUBJ">
                    <observation classCode="OBS" moodCode="EVN" negationInd="false">
                        <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.28"/>
                        <id extension="99999999" root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.441.1.50.869.51.1349970.61"/>
                        <code code="55607006"
                            codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.96"
                            codeSystemName="SNOMED CT" displayName="undescriptive display name2"/>
                        <text>
                            <reference value="#ref_b71a6ee05ef245f1a0c3f302ca769077_pastIllness_name_2"/>
                        </text>
                        <statusCode code="completed"/>
                        <effectiveTime>
                            <low value="20161230000000"/>
                        </effectiveTime>
                        <value code="783.3" codeSystemName="ICD9" displayName="undescriptive display name2">
                            <originalText>ref_b71a6ee05ef245f1a0c3f302ca769077_pastIllness_name_2</originalText>
                        </value>
                        <entryRelationship inversionInd="false" typeCode="REFR">
                            <observation classCode="OBS" moodCode="EVN">
                                <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.50"/>
                                <code code="33999-4"
                                    codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1"
                                    codeSystemName="LOINC" displayName="Status"/>
                                <statusCode code="Completed"/>
                                <value code="73425007"
                                    codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.96"
                                    codeSystemName="SNOMED CT" displayName="InActive"/>
                            </observation>
                        </entryRelationship>
                    </observation>
                </entryRelationship>
            </act>
        </entry>
    </section> </component>
```

Comment: So which elements do you want to define the key for, which `match` do you have in mind? And how do you want to relate a table row with an entry, by position?

Answer (score 0):

The `current()` function was useful when concatenating two elements based on a shared attribute/element value.

This is an example of a key for the xml in the original question:

```
<xsl:key name="testKey" match="/component/section/text/table/tbody/tr/td[1]" use="concat(.,'|',substring(../../../../../entry/act/effectiveTime[../entryRelationship/observation/value/originalText/text() = current()/@ID]/low/@value,1,8))"/>
```

Comment: this particular key was created to deduplicate based off of two element/attribute values